# Page not Redirecting from Application Error,

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url-rewriting

HI i am trying to Redirect Pages if HttpError is 404
it is working Perfect on local host but on Live site is not.

here is my code

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    HttpException serverError = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;

    if (serverError != null)
    {
        int errorCode = serverError.GetHttpCode();

        if (errorCode == 404)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("contact.php"))
            {
                Response.Redirect("contact-us.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks. Please advise how to get this to work on live,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. i had to write a rule in web.config for what ever Page i need to redirect

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="contact">
          <match url="^(contact).php$"/>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.example.com/contact-us.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This worked Perfectly on all pages i had to redirect. and added no code in global.asax

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the web.config for this rather than the global.asax file ?

```
<system.webServer>
          <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />                
            <error statusCode="404" path="contact-us.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />                
          </httpErrors>
       </system.webServer>
```

Comment: this is good for only one page.. i have more then 1 pages to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try  Response.Redirect("~/contact-us.aspx");